# Como executar uma funcao JS ou jQuery apos um update, reload em JSF e PrimeFaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Preciso executar essa função depois que um botao dá um update="@form" na pagina

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function carregaCss(){
        $(".ui-icon-calendar").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-calendar corPadrao");
        $(".ui-icon-seek-first").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-backward corPadrao");
        $(".ui-datepicker-next span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right");
    }
</script>
```

Ela funciona no cabeçalho da pagina, mas quando o update do ajax é executado ela nao funciona e os icones nao recebem as classes que deveriam receber..

Comment: Execute a função no callback do update do ajax...

Comment: Esta usando um `commandButton`? Dê uma olhada no atributo `onComplete` para chamar essa função.

Answer (score 1):

Para que a solução fique genérica, coloque um chamada a função dentro do formulário.

Assim, toda vez que um update for realizado no `form`, a função será chamada novamente, independente do componente que fez update no `form`.

Quando o `form` for renderizado novamente, a função será novamente chamada

A idéia é que fique parecido com:

```
<h:form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  carregaCSS();
 </script>
...
```

Comment: Hoje passei por uma situação parecido e a resposta do Felipe foi muito útil..

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço assim:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="@form" oncomplete="carregarCss()" />
```

o **oncomplete** é executado sempre que a requisição efetuada pelo componente for executado com sucesso. É equivalente ao **success** do ajax.

Comment: Eu tentei assim e não funcionou, até porque quando um campo atualiza o @form o css sai e nao funciona mais, pois nao é só os botoes que dao update="@form"

Comment: As classes dos seletores se perdem ao dar update nos componentes?

Comment: Isso.. Se perdem, nao atualizam junto com o form

Comment: Vc não consegue usar o atributo `styleClass` nesses componentes para poder buscar depois?

Comment: @Gerson, você consegue pegar os componentes usando id ou outra coisa? Eu acho que a resposta do [Felipe Fonseca](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29980/4050) vai te ajudar, coloque no final da página e veja se funciona.